# How to make a UITextView move up when keyboard is present

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

How to move **UITextView** Up and Down when you start entering some value. Like in TextField we use its delegate method. What to do in case of **UITextView** ?

Comment: `textFieldDidBecomeActive` > move text field accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present please see this link

Comment: Is the search that hard to use? Even if it is, look at the sidebar: it shows you related questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While editing complete View will move up and after done editing will move down...

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   [self animateTextView: YES];
 }

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
 {
   [self animateTextView:NO];
  }

- (void) animateTextView:(BOOL) up
    {
        const int movementDistance =heightKeyboard; // tweak as needed
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
        int movement= movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
        NSLog(@"%d",movement);

        [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.inputView.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

I hope this will help you...

Comment: Hum, you should use block for animation, your method is discouraged since iOS4

Comment: I faced lot of issues with this code. solved it by replacing         'self.inputView.frame' with 'self.view.frame' .

Comment: When you cannot use solution with scrollview, this is the easiest and best way

Comment: Here How you are getting height keyboard?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample code that will handle the keyboard automatically for you. [Keyboard avoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

If you are using TableView then your tableView must be a subclass of `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` and if you are using scrollview then your scrollview must be a subclass of `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`. And this library will automatically do keyboard handling for you.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to take a look at [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

in particular at section: *Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard*.
I have used this approach successfully several times.

Answer (score 3):

I did by changing the frame.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:viewMsg cache:YES];
viewMsg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 200);
[UIView commitAnimations];

NSLog(@"Started editing target!");

}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:viewMsg cache:YES];
viewMsg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 300, 200);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 80.0

-(void)keyboardWillShow {
    // Animate the current view out of the way
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:mailTf])
    {
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard 
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

try This CODE.....

Comment: there is alredy a question on same thing..

Comment: Annnnnddd you should use block for animation, your method is discouraged since iOS4...

Comment: This is answer for textField, not textView.

Comment: ...and you shouldn't use a constant for the keyboard size, you're encouraged to get the offset size from Apple.