# How To move UITextView above the keyboard in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

In My app, I have an form with contains `UITableView` and inside `UITableview` I have place Mutiple `UITextField` and UITextView.
Whenever i click on UITextfield or `UITextView` Keypad comes up.

I am able to move the `TextFiled` UP when user click on `UITextField` ones they want to enter the data.But i am now able to move the TextView up when user  want to enter the data.

Following is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:)
    name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

Can anyone help me out to move the `UITextView` UP above the keypad?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextView move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224161/how-to-make-a-uitextview-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

It will handle with frame when show hide keyboard for uitextfiled and uitextView.

And you make sure you do like this:

> Adding a "container" view in the case of a ScrollView with constraints set to the superview is also a good practice as follows: ViewController -> UIScrollView (TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView) -> UIView (container for UI elements) -> UITextView. If you want vertical scrolling set the height constraint to be '>='.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to handle this problem.

Features:

1) CODELESS, Zero Line Of Code

2) Works Automatically

3) No More UIScrollView

4) No More Subclasses

5) No More Manual Work

6) No More #imports

And its available for both languages (Swift and Objective C)